# How to send array in url in mule esb?

Tags: mule, esb

I need to send array in url. I have tried different ways like

```
http://localhost:8081/?RedundedItems[]=[00,11]
http://localhost:8081/?RedundedItems[]=00,11
http://localhost:8081/?RedundedItems=00&RedundedItems=11 
http://localhost:8081/?RedundedItems[]=00&RedundedItems[]=11
```

Please assist me.

Comment: What mule version are you using? What results do you get using each of those? The third option should allow you to retrieve the values from the property ```http.query.params```.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I really dont think this is possible or even if by some miracle it is, I dont see it as practical...

One solution would be to send your data as normal and maybe process it into an array via datamapper?

Hope I have been of some help.

JB

Answer (score 0):

The following works using your third option:

```
    <flow name="request-testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.getAll('RedundedItems')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
</flow>
```

So hitting `http://localhost:8081/?RedundedItems=00&RedundedItems=11` the output is: [00, 11].

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is http://localhost:8081/?RedundedItems=00,11 . You can't specify the parameter is an array.